# xsl variable value modification

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="sessionvalue">+xyz+</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="controller">1</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Properties/Data/Datum[@Name='My DCR']/DCR/tip_of_the_week/targeted_content">
            <xsl:variable name="dcrvalue"><xsl:value-of select="targeted_audiences"/></xsl:variable>
            <span>controller: <xsl:value-of select="$controller"/></span>
            <xsl:if test="$controller='1'">
            <xsl:if test="contains($dcrvalue,$sessionvalue)">
            <xsl:variable name="controller">0</xsl:variable>
                <p><xsl:value-of select="tip_header"/></p>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
```

I need to come out of the for each loop on one successful contains test. I see that there is break available in xslt neither can we values of a variable. Does anyone have any suggestion for this?

Comment: It would help if you explain what your input and output are, and how they relate to each other, rather than talking about how you would go about solving the problem in a procedural language.

Comment: my xml would contain multiple targeted_audiences. i need to match my input with these values and then do necessary action on the very first match. It can happen that there maybe multiple matches but i need to work on the very first match.

Comment: I meant, show the input XML and the output XML and if necessary explain how one relates to the other.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to come out of the for each loop on one successful contains
>   test.

No. What you need to do is test if at least one of the nodes satisfies the condition. No "loop" is necessary for this.

*I put "loop" in quotes, because `xsl:for-each` is not a loop.*

I cannot read your code, but in general it would look something like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="some/nodes[contains(sub-node, 'search-string')]">
        <!-- do something -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- do something else -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

---

### Edit

> It can happen that there maybe multiple matches but i need to work on
>   the very first match.

If that's your goal, then select the very first match directly, for example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="some/nodes[contains(sub-node, 'search-string')][1]">
    <!-- work on this node -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Again, no "loop" is necessary for this.